# I failed to slide screen animation in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, animation, qml

I want to slide the menu screen over to the root rectangle.  The menu screen comes from the left side, this is OK but I couldn't send it back again.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    id: root
    width: 460; height: 640
    color: "white"
    property int duration: 3000
    property bool menu_shown: false



    Rectangle {
        id: menu_screen
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height
        color: "#303030"
        radius: 10

        x: -460;
        SequentialAnimation {
            id: anim_menu
            NumberAnimation {
                target: menu_screen
                properties: "x"
                to: -160
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: click_button
        width: 50; height: 50
        color: "#303030"
        scale: m_area.pressed ? 1.1 : 1
        radius: 5

        x: 5; y: 5;
        SequentialAnimation {
            id: anim_button
            NumberAnimation {
                target: click_button
                properties: "x"
                to: 305

            }
        }

    }

    MouseArea {
        id: m_area
        anchors.fill: click_button
        onClicked : {
            anim_button.start()
            anim_menu.start()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining animation for going back, so it will always be the same animation that is running on the clicked signal.
I would recommend to use `Behavior on x` though.
Try something like this.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    id: root
    width: 460; height: 640
    color: "white"
    property int duration: 3000
    property bool menu_shown: false

    Rectangle {
        id: menu_screen
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height
        color: "#303030"
        radius: 10

        x: -460;

        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { } }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: click_button
        width: 50; height: 50
        color: "#303030"
        scale: m_area.pressed ? 1.1 : 1
        radius: 5

        x: 5; y: 5;

        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { } }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: m_area
        anchors.fill: click_button
        onClicked : {
            click_button.x = click_button.x == 5 ? 305 : 5
            menu_screen.x = menu_screen.x == -460 ? -160 : -460
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as a side note, take a look at [this](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qml-coding-conventions.html) in the meantime. :)

Answer (score 0):

When the main window is resized, the `menu_screen` becomes visible on the left side of the window. This is not, as I see it, to be expected. Also, you don't need to define behaviors for both the `menu_screen` and the `click_button`, but you can bind the `x` property of `click_button` as shown below. That way the button is also animated when menu screen is animated. You can also use `easing.type`, `duration` etc. of animation as shown here.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    id: root
    width: 460; height: 640
    color: "white"
    property int duration: 3000
    property bool menu_shown: false

    Rectangle {
        id: menu_screen
        width: 310; height: parent.height
        color: "#303030"
        radius: 10

        x: -width;

        Behavior on x {
            NumberAnimation {
                target: menu_screen
                property: "x"
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: click_button
        width: 50; height: 50
        color: "#303030"
        scale: m_area.pressed ? 1.1 : 1
        radius: 5

        x: menu_screen.x + menu_screen.width + 5; y: 5;

    }

    MouseArea {
        id: m_area
        anchors.fill: click_button
        onClicked : {
            menu_screen.x = menu_screen.x === -menu_screen.width ? -10 : -menu_screen.width
        }
    }
}
```